# format curl results in php

Tags: php, json, curl

Below I have a piece of code to return some information through an API.

```
$page = 'http://api.duedil.com/sandbox/v2/company/03977902.json?    fields=get_all&api_key=***********';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This prints out the following results http://www.visitrack.co.uk/testdata.php

what i am trying to do is split the results in to individual variables.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // forces curl_exec() to return page as a string
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE); // parse json string to array
print_r($data);
```